# Regex for filenames without using lookbehind

Tags: regex, macos, find, file-extension

I'm trying to match all files which don't end in `jpg`/`png`/`jpeg`/`gif`, and which also do not have a filename starting with a `.`.

I'm passing this regex into `find` like so:

```
find -E path/to/dir myregex
```

Here's the regex

```
^.*\/[^\.].*\.(?!jpeg$)(?!jpg$)(?!gif$)(?!png$)([^jgp]..|j[^p].|g[^i].|p[^n].|jp[^g]|gi[^f]|pn[^g]|jpg.+|png.+|gif.+|jpe[^g]|jpeg.+)[^\.]*$
```

It does appear to work, but man is it long... One possibility would be to write a function to generate it... but I wish there was an easier way.

I don't think the version of `find` that I'm using (OS X Mavericks) supports lookbehind, but even if it did, I'd like to know if there was an alternative.

Here's an interactive version: http://regex101.com/r/xD9qC2/1

Comment: Are you sure `find` supports look-ahead? I have looked at Mac's documentation of `find` and `re_format`, but I can't see anything about look-ahead.

Comment: Did you consider `find path/to/dir -not -iname "*.jpg" -not -iname "*.jpeg" -not -iname "*.png" -not -iname "*.gif" -not -iname ".*"`?

Comment: @Ken Thanks for pointing that out. I didn't know about -iname or -not. Guess I should RTFM.

Comment: Why do you need lookbehind? Wouldn't something like `'.*/\.[^/]*\(jpg\|png\|jpeg\|giff\)$'` work?

Comment: @BroSlow That regex matches filenames *with* those extensions.

Comment: @AmadeusDrZaius Ah, that makes sense. I missed the comment above so was wondering why not `! -regex` or `-not regex`

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the self Q&A here. I spent a while thinking about this before posting my question, but just after posting I had some insight.

It's a little long but it's less brute-forced than the one in the question.

```regex
(?:^.{1,3}$)|(?:^(?!\.(?:jpg|gif|png)$).{4}$)|(?:^.*(?!.*\.(?:jpg|gif|png|jpeg)$).{5}$)
```

[Interactive link](http://regex101.com/r/cA8dC5/3)